# Not a programmer, just a user with an app scripts challenge

Tags: macos, email, google-apps-script

I am recieving apps-scripts-notifications@google.com - I have no idea why or how to cease these which are coming to my inbox through the day. Jeff Cunningham

here is a sample of the message

> our script, Mail to Drive, has recently failed to finish successfully.
>   A summary of the failure(s) is shown below. To configure the triggers
>   for this script, or change your setting for receiving future failure
>   notifications, click here.
>
> Summary: Error Message    Count Authorization is required to perform that
>   action.   288
>
> Details: Start    Function    Error Message   Trigger End 10/11/13 2:51
>   AM    runGmailToDrive Authorization is required to perform that
>   action.   time-based  10/11/13 2:51 AM 10/11/13 2:56
>   AM    runGmailToDrive Authorization is required to perform that
>   action.   time-based  10/11/13 2:56 AM 10/11/13 3:01
>   AM    runGmailToDrive Authorization is required to perform that
>   action.   time-based  10/11/13

Comment: So then why dont you actually try and follow the instructions in that mail and "click here".

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to remove the trigger itself, even if you're not sure in which file it is.  Go to any Google Sheet, then click on Tools -> Script Editor.  Once there, Click Resources -> All My Triggers.
In there you can click the "x" icon to the left of any trigger to remove it.

Answer (score -1):

Go to Google.com, then click your account picture in the top-right corner of the screen. Next, click Account, then Security, then Review permissions. Click Revoke Access next to the "Mail to Drive" script whose authorization you want to revoke.

Comment: he already said the script has no permission. the trigger is running but needs permissions to run thus the error email.

Comment: Because the notifications are arriving in the inbox, it likely means that one of the script is authorized to run a trigger at certain intervals. To cease the notifications, an option would be to revoke access to any script.

Comment: Not relevant to the question, but +Amit - the shortcut to the Revoke Access is this link - https://accounts.google.com/issuedauthsubtokens